# When do scorpions appear, and how do I catch them?

Tags: animal-crossing-new-leaf

In **Animal Crossing: New Leaf**, I have seen a scorpion only once. It was in front of the mayor's office, and when I got close to it, I fell and my game reset. Does anyone know how to catch it? Even more, **WHEN** are scorpions usually active?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Scorpions are active between 7pm - 4am, only during the months of July, August, and September. [source](http://animalcrossing.wikia.com/wiki/Bugs_%28New_Leaf%29)

To catch a scorpion:

> Scorpions will attack the player if they walk too fast around it while a net is equipped, or if the player uses the net nearby and misses it. Walking slowly and capturing it is usually fairly simple, so it is generally advised not to run or even walk at normal speed when searching for them, at least when walking down as visibility is decreased when traveling in this direction. If the scorpion notices a player when they are not holding a net, it will wander away. Equipping a net at this time often initiates an attack as well.

[source](http://animalcrossing.wikia.com/wiki/Scorpion)